# Determine mysql client version

Tags: mysql, centos

How to determine the current mysql client version in cent os? I've tried using select variables like "%version%".I'm assuming that select now() gives server version but not client version. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
mysql --version
```

It will output something like:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```